# Bash, arithmetic expression + bc

Tags: bash, unix, bc

I have small problem with use bc command in unix. I have two varaibles:
variable1, variable2. The arithmetic expression looks like:

```
res=$$((($variable1*10)/$variable2)
```

I would like to round the result from two divided numbers. I think, the best solution will be using `bc -l` command + `scale=X`, but doesn't work.

```
res=$$(((echo "scale=2; $variable1*10)/$variable2" | bc -l)
```

I would like to get more exact result. Now, f.e., I have:

```
res = 10
```

But should be

```
res = 9.23
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is *not* a very good problem report. You should be specifying what you want it to do and what it actually does (in some detail).

Comment: True, was changed some information. I would like to get more precise result.

Answer (score 2):

What you currently have won't work simply because the parentheses in the `bc` expression are unbalanced. In addition, you appear to have *way* more `$`, `(` and `)` characters in there than you need.

Without those flaws, it works fine:

```
pax> num=923
pax> den=1000
pax> res=$(echo "scale=2; $num * 10 / $den" | bc -l)
pax> echo $res
9.23
```

Comment: Indeed, my problem was with to have to much signs $,(.). It works perfectly now.